# dropdown in gridview, find GridRow on OnSelectedIndexChanged

Tags: asp.net, datagridview

I have a asp.net gridview. A template field of type dropdownlist is contained in a column:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderTextLabel="strManagedOETeamart">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="SelectedTeamartChanged">
                                <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="White"> White </asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="Silver"> Silver </asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="DarkGray"> Dark Gray </asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="Khaki"> Khaki </asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="DarkKhaki"> Dark Khaki </asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

How can I get the GridViewRow when the user selects another item?

```
    protected void SelectedTeamartChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList dropDown = (DropDownList) sender;
        //I would like to know the GridViewRow this DropDownList is in

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [`NamingContainer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.namingcontainer.aspx) property:

```
GridViewItem row = (GridViewRow)dropDown.NamingContainer;
```

By the way, that works for any kind of web databound control like `GridView`, `DataList`,`Repeater` or `ListView`.

Consider this more complex requirement: you have a `GridView` which is nested in another `GridView`. Now you're handling a DropDownList's `SelectedIndexChanged` event that is inside the child's `GridView` and you want to get the reference to the `GridViewRow` of the parent `GridView`:

```
var control = (Control)sender;
var row = (GridViewRow)control.NamingContainer;
var parentRow = (GridViewRow)row.NamingContainer.NamingContainer;
```

That's the safest and easiest way to get it.